# Proof that all Quotient Groups are Abelian- where is my error?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, quotient-group

I'm having trouble finding the error in my proof:

**Theorem:** If H is a normal subgroup of G, then the quotient group G/H is abelian.

**Proof:** $\forall x, y \in G$, $xy(yx)^{-1} = xyy^{-1}x^{-1} = e \in H$. By the lemma, $H(xy) = H(yx)$, thus $HxHy= HyHx$. This shows that the commutative property holds for all the elements in the quotient group G/H, therefore G/H is abelian.

**Lemma:** Let H be a subgroup of G. Then $Ha = Hb \iff ab^{-1} \in H$. Proof: We start with the $\Rightarrow$ direction. $Ha = Hb$ implies $a \in Hb$, thus $a=hb$ for some $h \in H$. Therefore $ab^{-1} = h \in H$. For the reverse direction, if $ab^{-1} = h \in H$ then $a=hb$ for some $h \in H$. Thus $a \in Hb$, and since we also have $a \in Ha$, $Ha = Hb$ (because cosets partition a group).

Comment: The identity element is always a normal subgroup.  Do you suppose that means that every group is abelian?

Comment: You must need an additional hypothesis. Every group is a quotient group, in particular of itself by the trivial subgroup, but need not be abelian.

Comment: lulu, walkar: the OP clearly knows the "theorem" is false. (S)he was not asking for  counterexamples but for finding the mistake in the "proof". Admittedly, a counterexample may be useful when letting the alledged proof work on it and see where things go wrong.

Comment: You have used $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ as an identity, which is equivalent to $G$ being abelian. This is a circular argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the first line of your proof: $xy(yx)^{-1}$ is not $xyy^{-1}x^{-1}$ (unless $G$ is itself abelian). Instead $xy(yx)^{-1}=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, which is not guaranteed to simplify to $e$.

---

Bringing in a bit of jargon, the point is that the "inversion" map $$G\rightarrow G: g\mapsto g^{-1}$$ is only guaranteed to be an "antihomomorphism" instead of a homomorphism: we have $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$, and you can see that by multiplying $$(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)=b^{-1}(a^{-1}a)b=b^{-1}b=e.$$ In fact, the statement "$(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$" (or "inversion is a homomorphism") is **equivalent to** the abelian-ness of the group in question. Essentially, this is what your argument actually shows: if your first sentence is justified, then indeed the group in question is abelian.